# htaccess - How to rewrite this

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect all requests to: **domain.com** to a subfolder **/sub**, though i do not want that subfolder to show in url so that my url remains **domain.com**.

Is this possible at all ?

**EDIT:** After trying all of the suggestions i still get URL looking like `domain.com/sub` whenever i go to `domain.com`

Here is my current code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?sub.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ en [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?sub.domain.fr$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ fr [L]
```

My folder structure is:

/
->en
->fr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in you htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?sub/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Edit :**

Just to do some cleaning on your posted code, it should be :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ /en/ [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub\.domain\.fr$
RewriteRule ^$ /fr/ [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, though all of these suggestions end up giving me a URL of domain.com/sub.

Comment: just added the content of my htaccess. Thanks again

Comment: did you clear your cache before trying again ? (the old redirection may still be cached so even if you change your htaccess you get redirected again)

Comment: Yeah i noticed that even though my browser is not supposed to cache anything it still caches the dNS, still the same after refreshing cache

Comment: I edited my answer and posted your own code after cleaning it a bit. as for why you are still getting redirected to /sub folder I don't have an answer because you shouldn't unless you add the R flag.

Comment: Thanks again, i ended adding Options +FollowSymLinks and it seems to have fixed it. Does that make any sense?

Comment: It does if one of your directories was a link to naother directory :|

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sub%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sub%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/$1 [L]
```

This will ensure that if you request something that doesn't exist in `/sub/` the 404 response won't expose that you're routing everything to `/sub/`.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite rules work on server side (so they don't affect the URL).
You should really read about mod_rewrite and try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Using mode rewrite you can do something along the lines of this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ sub [L]
```

You can read more here: http://www.blogstorm.co.uk/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/sub/.*$   [NC]
RewriteRule  ^(?<!sub/)(.*)$   /sub/$2   [L,NC]
```